# When I create a new fragment, the related XML file isn't recognised

Tags: android

It was working fine, but after an update when I create a new fragment, there is an error. It says that the layout resource file isn't recognised( Cannot resolve symbol 'blank'). I created the fragment and layout file together so I don't know why there is an issue. Not sure what to do. I've tried creating new fragments but the problem persists.

[Showing the error that occurs when I create a new fragment.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o57QK.png)

Comment: `Clean` & `Rebuild` your project or `Invalidate Caches / Restart`

Answer (score 0):

So I downloaded a new theme and I had to restart android studio and in doing so the error went away. I guess I just had to restart android studio.